# How to update specific value when the state is an array of objects - React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJs and I'm trying to do a simple summary basket for an ipotetic e-commerce: when you add a product you need to know if it's already there and in that case increase only the item number.

As you can see if the row doesn't exist I do a concat (row it's a object

```
{ 
  id: singleProd.id, 
  name: singleProd.name, 
  price: singleProd.price,              
  value: 1 
}
```

), but if exist I need to increase just the value property

```
state = {
    counters: []
  };

  addCounter = row => {
    let countersRows = this.state.counters;
    let existRow = countersRows.filter(c => c.id === row.id);

    if (existRow.length !== 0) {
      let index = countersRows.findIndex(x => x.id === existRow[0].id);
      console.log("Update here... like this.state.counters[index].value + 1?");
    } else {
      this.setState({ counters: countersRows.concat(row) });
    }
  };

  deleteRow = counterId => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
```

I heard about Object assign, but I don't know how to do.
Thanks so much.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEzBo.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are just trying to increment the value property of the first item with a matching ID. If so, is this what you want?

```
addCounter = row => {
  const { counters } = this.state;
  const existingRow = counters.filter(c => c.id === row.id)[0];

  if (existingRow.length !== 0) {
    this.setState(
      Object.assign(existingRow, { value: existingRow.value + 1 })
    );
  } else {
    this.setState({ counters: counters.concat(row) });
  }
};
```

Comment: Perfect, this works for the state: now the only problem I have it's about updating the map component based on the array...why it's updating for the concat and it's not updating with the object assign?

Comment: Do you mean it's not updating if an existing row isn't found? You will need to check for null first, before checking if the length is !== 0. See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jlk4w81pw5

Comment: Thank you so much! Now, as you can see from the image, I can change the value from the component and from the product!

Answer (score 0):

**Do not mutate state!**

> In your example you are mutating the existing state object, which is a
>   bad practice.

The proper way to do this is to consider the existing state counters immutable. Then generate a brand new counters array.

```
addCounter = row => {

  const { counters } = this.state;

  //map creates a brand new array
  let newCounters = counters.map((existingRow, index) => {
      if(index === row.id){
          if (existingRow.length !== 0) {
              //Using Object assign Copies all values  from existing row and the object literal to a brand new object
              //return Object.assign({}, existingRow, { value: existingRow.value + 1 });
              //Also instead use the spread operator for more clarity
              return {
                  ...existingRow,
                  value: existingRow.value+1
              };
          } else {
              return row;
          }
      }

      //Just return all other object
      return item;
  });

  this.setState({ counters : newCoutners });
}
```

Check [this](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) article in the Redux docs for more details on how to do immutable updates.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: if I understood correctly, it's better to create a copy and assign it? As I said, I'm new to React, thanks for the help!